# when setting the value of an input field, it just appears for a brief moment.

Tags: javascript, input

I am sure I am missing some basic part here, but have a look at my very simple code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showscore(){

var score = document.createTextNode("test");
var placeholder = document.getElementById("field");
placeholder.value = score.nodeValue;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" id="field"/>
<input type="submit" value="Show score" onclick="javascript:showscore()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it, the result (for the moment, the word "test") appears inside the input field for a very brief moment and then goes away.

What extremely simple and easy thing I am missing? :-)

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the page is submitting the form. Just change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` or prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the solution in the wrong place, didn't realize about that mistake...

Answer (score 1):

It's because your button is an `<input type="submit />` so after your Javascript is executed, the browser submits the form.

If you don't want the form to submit, you could use an `<input type="button" />` instead.

Alternatively you could leave it as a `submit` and `return false;` after the `showscore()` call. That will prevent the form from submitting.